# Запросы на сайты с помощью fetch

Tags: javascript

Всем привет! Можно ли сделать запрос через javascript на сайт facebook.com или instagram.com... Если да то как?

Comment: _с помощью fetch_ - у тебя ответ в самом заголовке указан

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Запрос делать можно, но далеко не все сайты позволяют делать запросы к себе. Точнее сказать почти никто не будет давать разрешения делать к себе запрос. Более подробно об этом можно прочитать тут https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

Ответ на вопрос "как" достаточно прост

```
fetch('https://facebook.com/')
    .then(r => r.body())
    .then(body => console.log(body))
    .catch(e => console.error(e))
```

Comment: Всё понятно, спасибо)